# JavascriptExecutor for scrolling does not work with selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

This what I have tried

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
JavascriptExecutor js3 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js3.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");
```

But the page does not scroll down, is there perhaps another way of scroll down on a form, because when I am trying the above the form won't scroll so I am not able to get to the below element.

I want to scroll down to this element on the form.

```
'<div class="ant-select-selection__rendered" style=""><div unselectable="on" class="ant-select-selection__placeholder" style="display: none; user-select: none;">Select...</div><div title="" class="ant-select-selection-selected-value" style="display: block; opacity: 1;"></div></div>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below way. I extracted the locator from your given `html` make sure its unique.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ant-select-selection__rendered"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Comment: I am not sure, why this is accepted as an answer. As I have seen the same advise on other websites and tried it, but this method did not work. I am using Selenium v4.12.1. Is the version of Selenium a problem ?

Comment: @ PraNuta - If the answer resolve the OP issue than its on OP discretion to accept it as answer or not. We can't see your `code` we can't say you're facing the same `issue` or not

Comment: My bad. Later to your comment, I tried the same/similar(multiple variations) code given below and all of them are working on the desktop web, but not on mobileweb. So I can say I verified that the JavaScriptExecutor is working on desktop, but not on mobileweb.

Comment: public void scrollJSVertical(RemoteWebDriver driver,double ratio) {
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   js.executeScript(String.format("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * %.1f)",ratio));
  }

Comment: public void scrollByJS(RemoteWebDriver driver,int x, int y) {
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,900)", "");
  }

Comment: public void scrollJS4ElementVisibility(RemoteWebDriver driver,WebElement elm) {
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm);
  }